# Why does this while loop not break?

Tags: python, input

This loop does not break if h,l, or c is input:

```
x = input('enter h,l, or c')
while (x != 'c') or (x != 'h') or (x != 'l'):
    print('Sorry I didn't understand. Please enter h,l, or c')
    x = input("enter h,l, or c")
```

What I was intending can be solved this way:

```
x = input("enter h,l, or c")
while True:
    if x == 'c' or x == 'h' or x == 'l':
        break
    else:
        print('Sorry I didnt understand. Please enter h,l, or c')
        x = input("enter h,l, or c")
```

What is incorrect of the first piece of code? Does X not get evaluated at the beginning of the while?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code. These techniques can also be used to learn how working code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your condition:

```
while (x != 'c') or (x != 'h') or (x != 'l'):
```

Consider the case where the input character is `c`.  The first condition is `False`, but the other two are `True`.  F or T or T is `True`.

You need `and` connectors in your condition.  Better yet, try

```
while not x in ['h', 'l', 'c']:
```

Comment: Your solution is wrong because it accepts all inputs made of a combination of "hlc". You must use `while not x in ("h", "l", "c"):`.

Comment: Well, you could try to find someone who has never made this mistake, but it could be a long hunt.

Answer (score 3):

You should have used `and` condition rather than `or`. That is if it is one of the accepted letters, then `(x != 'c')`, `(x != 'h')`, and `(x != 'h')` are evaluated to be false.

```
x = input('enter h,l, or c')
while (x != 'c') and (x != 'h') and (x != 'l'):
    print("Sorry I didn't understand. Please enter h,l, or c")
    x = input("enter h,l, or c")
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of an error on the logic operation.

> not (A or B)

This logic equals to

> (not A) and (not B)

So the first code should be

```
x = input('enter h,l, or c')
while (x != 'c') and (x != 'h') and (x != 'l'):
    print("Sorry I didn't understand. Please enter h,l, or c")
    x = input("enter h,l, or c")
```

Answer (score 1):

Let start with the statement that `false or true` is evaluated to *true*. Therefore if `x` is `c` then the `(x != 'c')` will be *false*, but the second case `(x != 'h')` will be *true*, and according to our first statement the whole `or` expression will evaluate to *true* so your loop will never exit. Instead what you need to is:

```py
x = input('enter h,l, or c')
while not ((x == 'c') or (x == 'h') or (x == 'l')):
    print("Sorry I didn't understand. Please enter h,l, or c")
    x = input("enter h,l, or c")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop will always evaluate to `True`

```
0 x = input('enter h,l, or c')
1 while (x != 'c') or (x != 'h') or (x != 'l'):
2    print('Sorry I didn't understand. Please enter h,l, or c')
3    x = input("enter h,l, or c")
```

Your code has become something like this:

```
0 x = input('enter h,l, or c')
1 while True:
2    print('Sorry I didn't understand. Please enter h,l, or c')
3    x = input("enter h,l, or c")
```

Let's explain.

INPUT SCENARIOS:

a. If input is 'z', z is not equal to any of the letters so it becomes `True` for all the conditions. This means any input that is not one of 'h', 'l', 'c', will evaluate to `True`.

b. If input is 'h', h is neither equal to l nor c. This evaluates to a `True OR False OR True` scenario and obviously becomes a `True`. Thus, if your input is also any of the letters specified, it will be a `True` because it is not equal to the other letters in the condition, and just a single `True` is required for an `OR` condition to evaluate to `True`.

So your current code will ALWAYS evaluate to True, and the loop will run infinitely. You need to use `AND` instead of `OR`, use the second code you posted, or you can use recursion.

RECOMMENDED OPTIONS:

1. Use AND

```
x = input('enter h,l, or c')
while (x != 'c') and (x != 'h') and (x != 'l'):
    print("Sorry I didn't understand. Please enter h,l, or c")
    x = input("enter h,l, or c")
```

2. Recursion

```
def checker():
    x = input("enter h,l, or c")
    if (x != 'c') and (x != 'h') and (x != 'l'):
        print("Sorry I didn't understand. Please enter h,l, or c")
        checker()

checker()
```